# Datasample - Prevent duplicate sampling - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 1D matrix that mostly contains 0's however it also contains dispersed peaks of probability that peak at a value of 1. I need to be able to carry out weighted sampling of the matrix such that a random numbers fall within the peaks only.

I am using

```
datasample(1:100,3,'Weights',x)
```

However have realised that this can return the same value twice or more. Is there an easy way to prevent duplicate selections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Replace` option that needs to be set to `false` (`true` by default).

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html